# Is it possible to enable NFS Services in PCFDev?

Tags: nfs, cloud-foundry, pcfdev

I'm using PCF Dev Environment on a Windows Host in order to test an application I'm developing. My app needs to access several files that are stored on a NFS Volume.

I know that as an PCF Operator you can redeploy Cloud Foundry and add
The NFS Volume Service Type to your plattform (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nfs-volume-release).

The PCF Dev  uses Bosh Director to deploy so I've installed the BOSH Cli and tried to redeploy the VM.

The Problem is that I neither have got any idea about which configuration to use nor know if it generally works.

So my question is, it is possible to redeploy the PC Dev Environment  in order to add the NFS Volume Service?

Comment: Have you tried the instructions in this section -> https://github.com/cloudfoundry/nfs-volume-release#redeploy-cloud-foundry-with-nfs-enabled? You might be able to just `bosh deploy` and update the settings to include the NFS release. You might also try the release from Pivotal Networks, it's supposed to mimic Pivotal CF which should have NFS volume services enabled by default. https://network.pivotal.io/products/pcfdev/

Comment: The release from Pivotal Networks has only enabled the same four services as the Community version on github, which are MySQL,RabbitMQ, Redis and Spring Cloud Services. I've tried the instructions to redeploy: At the beginning it starts to work, but after a while it returns an error claiming about "unknown vm type minimal in group smoke-tests". Is it possible to create a cf-deployment.yml from the existing PCF Dev environment?

Comment: Under `~/.cfdev/services` is where cfdev stores all the manifest files that it generated for your deployments. In theory, you'd need that plus the operations file from `cf-deployment` for enabling NFS. With those you should be able to re-run the deployment and turn on NFS. It may not be that easy in practice though. If the cf deployment manifest is different the operations file might not apply cleanly. You might need to manually go through and edit the `cf.yml` file to make the changes (you can see what needs to be changed in the operations file), or work through some other issues.

Comment: `"unknown vm type minimal in group smoke-tests"` -> you need to look at your cloud config and see what vm types exist. The operations file probably expects one called "minimal", but you don't have that. You could create one or your could just change the operations file to use a vm type that you do have.